# Embedding 2d plot into a 3d plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d

I have a set of data vectors z that has this 2d plot [image]

How would I go about embed this set of data into a 3d plot like this in matlab? I'm asking for advice and suggestions. The theory I'm trying to employ is "for each data vector~zj, “copies” the data vector intothe first two entries of a 3D data vector~yjand then computes the squared length of~zj as the third entry of~yj. " or kernel trick.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your 2d data will somehow be in the form, that you have x-coordinates and y-coordinates. Let's say you have a vector **x** and a vector **y** for simplification.

As you found out the `plot3`-function proivdes functionality to plot arbitrary points in 3d without the need of generating a mesh. What you need additionally is a third vector **z** with data for the 3rd dimension.

So what else can you do? The thing I am thinking about is rotating the plane you are plotting you "2d" data:

Rotational matrices can be seen here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix